# aggregate pandas groupby all

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe that looks like the one given below.

```
item_id length height shape color
a       True
a       True
a              False
a              True
a                     True
b       True
b              True
b                     False
b                           True
```

i want to do something like

```
data_df.groupby('item_id').all().reset_index()
```

to convert the dataframe to

```
item_id length height shape color
a       True   False  True  False
b       True   True   False True
```

my problem is with color for item a which should be false as it does not exist but it comes out as true.

Comment: Are `True/False` the string `'True'/'False'` or the boolean values?

Comment: they are boolean values

Answer (score 0):

You can do a logical AND between the the usual `df.groupby('item_id').all()` frame and another frame representing whether each column has at least a non-NaN value for each group.

```
df.groupby('item_id').all() & ~df.iloc[:,1:].isnull().groupby(df['item_id']).all()
```

Output

```
    length  height  shape   color
item_id             
a   True    False   True    False
b   True    True    False   True
```

In terms of speed, I did a little benchmark on a dataframe with 10k rows.

```
%%timeit -r 4 -n 100
df.groupby('item_id').all()

%%timeit -r 4 -n 100
df.groupby('item_id').all() & ~df.iloc[:,1:].isnull().groupby(df['item_id']).all()
```

When there are 9997 different groups (~1 row per group)

```
Incorrect solution: 31.1 ms ± 910 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 100 loops each)
Correct solution: 45.8 ms ± 1.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 100 loops each)
```

When there are 625 different groups (~16 rows per group)

```
Incorrect solution: 24 ms ± 211 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 100 loops each)
Correct solution: 30.7 ms ± 417 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 100 loops each)
```

So the speed of the correct solution should be on the same order as that of the incorrect one.

Comment: it may work but it will be a lot slower than data_df.groupby('item_id').all().reset_index()

Comment: I came up with a new solution and update my answer.